# Enabling Oculus Quest's Hand Tracking in Unity XR Interaction Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

**XRCameraRig** is supposed to replace **OVRCameraRig** but OVRCameraRig is the only place where you can set hand tracking support ("Hands only" or "Controllers and hands"). That option is not available on XRRig so including hands makes **the app to be recognized by Oculus Quest as a "hands only" app.**

- How  can I use both hands and controllers in a UnityXR app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it. Don't use the new XR Management System.

**Remove** the following packages:

- *XR Management*
- *XR Interaction Subsystems*
- *Oculus XR Plugin*

**Install** the following packages:

- *Oculus Android (2.38.6)*
- *Oculus Desktop (2.38.4)*
- *OpenVR Desktop (2.0.5)*
- *XR Legacy Input Helpers (1.3.11)*

Change the **AndroidManifest**:

Make sure this line is missing:

```
<meta-dataandroid:value="false" android:name="com.oculus.vr.focusaware" >
</meta-data>
```

Make sure hand tracking is not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="oculus.software.handtracking" android:required="false">
```

Make sure intent-filter category is LAUNCHER, not INFO:

```
<intent-filter>
...
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
</intent-filter>
```

Make sure you only have these meta-data elements:

```
<meta-data
android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
android:value="false">
</meta-data>
<meta-data
android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode"
android:value="vr_only">
</meta-data>
```

I hope we could change hand tracking and controllers while using the new XR Management System in the future